# Infopath 2007 Submit Error: "folder does not exist"

Tags: infopath

I have about 15 users submitting Infopath forms to a subsite on a Sharepoint 2007 site.  The users are set up through PRACS and I think they are all using Infopath 2007.  Only 1 of the users is getting the following error when he submits the Infopath form (*I have truncated the URLs for security reasons*):

> InfoPath cannot submit the form. Some rules were not applied. InfoPath
>   cannot submit the form. An error occurred while the form was being
>   submitted. The form cannot be submitted to the following location:
>   /IMD_2011/IMD_Open/IMD_12474604-1.xml The folder does not exist.

The file "IMD_12474604-1.xml" does not exist because it could not be created, however the folder/form library "/IMD_2011/IMD_Open/" definitely exists (that was where this form was opened from).  This user is able to submit the form via the browser-enabled form which is based on the exact same template as the Infopath form and submits to the same folder/form library although it is opened from a different form library ("/IMD_2011/IMD_Open_Web/).

Any suggested solutions are welcome.

Comment: The same problem I am facing.. Only one user gets this error. Any reason?

Answer (score 1):

That can happen if the URL gets too long. The whole encoded path including the form name in the forms library must be under 128 characters. So it is essential to keep names as short as possible to stay within that limit.

More information:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ff919564(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the InfoPath file that you are saving has invalid characters in the filename. Compare the filenames when it gets saved and when it does not and check for illegal characters if any.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saying that the file name has illegal characters. You wouldn't be able to save a file with illegal characters. The name of my template is 'Monitoring Onboarding Questionnaire'. I am getting the same error message discussed above.